# Is there a sequence $(x_n) \subset E$ such that $|x_n|=1$ for all $n$ and that $x_n \to 0$ in $\sigma(E, E^*)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-topology

Let $(E, |\cdot|)$ be an infinite-dimensional Banach space and $\sigma(E, E^*)$ its weak topology.

> Is there a sequence $(x_n) \subset E$ such that $|x_n|=1$ for all $n$ and that $x_n \to 0$ in $\sigma(E, E^*)$?

In case $E^*$ is separable or $E$ is reflexive, the answer is [affirmative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4395850/breziss-ex-3-22-if-e-is-reflexive-there-is-a-sequence-of-norm-1-that-weak). If the answer is negative, we fix $\varepsilon >0$.

> Is there a sequence $(x_n) \subset E$ such that $|x_n| \ge \varepsilon$ for all $n$ and that $x_n \to 0$ in $\sigma(E, E^*)$?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Comment: What do you think in the case $E = l^1$ ?  It is not reflexive and the dual is not separable.  So... does it have such a sequence?

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208898/schurs-theorem-in-ell1-weak-convergence-of-x-n-is-the-same-as-convergenc)